# Android BaseAdapter with Animation to ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, baseadapter

I have created Base Adapter and applying animation to image-view which is part of that custom layout after every 3 second. Each row is having array of images so I'm trying to fade-out current image and fad-in new one.I have created handler with runnable timer in activity which is calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after every 3 second. Without applying animation my adapter would be like as below :

```
public class FerrariAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

/*
 * Variable Declaration Part
 */

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mTitle, mOwner, mDate;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mImages;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mLastImagePosition;
private ViewHolder mHolder;
private boolean is_animation = false;
private Animation mFadeIn, mFadeOut;

/* Constructor that initialize variables getting from activity */

public FerrariAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mTitle,
        ArrayList<String> mOwner, ArrayList<String> mDate,
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mImages,
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mLastImagePosition) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mOwner = mOwner;
    this.mDate = mDate;
    this.mImages = mImages;
    this.mLastImagePosition = mLastImagePosition;
    mFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadeout);
    mFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadein);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mTitle.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mTitle.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View mView = convertView;
    if (mView == null) {

        /*
         * Inflating custom layout and getting components IDs to set each
         * row of ListView
         */

        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.car_tile,
                null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.mTitleHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.titleHolder);
        mHolder.mOwnerHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.OwnerHolder);
        mHolder.mDateHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateHolder);
        mHolder.mImageHolder = (ImageView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);

        mView.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
    }

    /* Set Value to each row */

    mHolder.mTitleHolder.setText(mTitle.get(position));
    mHolder.mOwnerHolder.setText(mOwner.get(position));
    mHolder.mDateHolder.setText(Utils.millisToDate(
            Long.parseLong(mDate.get(position)), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"));

    mHolder.mImageHolder.setImageBitmap(getImagefromHashmap(position));
    /*mFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    mHolder.mImageHolder.setAnimation(mFadeOut);*/

    return mView;
}

/*
 * This class is used to hold position of each component so it shouln't be
 * repeat again and again
 */

class ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImageHolder;
    TextView mTitleHolder, mOwnerHolder, mDateHolder;

}

private Bitmap getImagefromHashmap(int position) {

    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    ArrayList<String> mImagesList = mImages.get(mTitle.get(position));
    int mLastImagePostion = mLastImagePosition.get(position);

    if (mImagesList.size() - 1 > mLastImagePostion) {

        mLastImagePostion++;
        mLastImagePosition.put(position, mLastImagePostion);

    } else {

        mLastImagePostion = 0;
        mLastImagePosition.put(position, mLastImagePostion);

    }

    String mImageName = mImagesList.get(mLastImagePostion);
    // Get the AssetManager
    AssetManager manager = mContext.getAssets();

    // Read a Bitmap from Assets
    try {
        InputStream mOpen = manager.open(mImageName);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mOpen);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return Utils.resize(mBitmap,
            (int) (Utils.getDeviceWidth(mContext) / 2.5),
            Utils.getDeviceHeight(mContext) / 5);

}
}
```

And it is working well by changing image to imageview with each row. Now when I'm going to apply animation on getview(), Only last row is getting affected. So I think getView() is called before completion of animation for the each row. While applying animation :

```
public class FerrariAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

/*
 * Variable Declaration Part
 */

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mTitle, mOwner, mDate;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mImages;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mLastImagePosition;
private ViewHolder mHolder;
private boolean is_animation = false;
private Animation mFadeIn, mFadeOut;

/* Constructor that initialize variables getting from activity */

public FerrariAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mTitle,
        ArrayList<String> mOwner, ArrayList<String> mDate,
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mImages,
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mLastImagePosition) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mOwner = mOwner;
    this.mDate = mDate;
    this.mImages = mImages;
    this.mLastImagePosition = mLastImagePosition;
    mFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadeout);
    mFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadein);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mTitle.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mTitle.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View mView = convertView;
    if (mView == null) {

        /*
         * Inflating custom layout and getting components IDs to set each
         * row of ListView
         */

        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.car_tile,
                null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.mTitleHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.titleHolder);
        mHolder.mOwnerHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.OwnerHolder);
        mHolder.mDateHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateHolder);
        mHolder.mImageHolder = (ImageView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);

        mView.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
    }

    /* Set Value to each row */

    mHolder.mTitleHolder.setText(mTitle.get(position));
    mHolder.mOwnerHolder.setText(mOwner.get(position));
    mHolder.mDateHolder.setText(Utils.millisToDate(
            Long.parseLong(mDate.get(position)), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"));


    mFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mHolder.mImageHolder.setImageBitmap(getImagefromHashmap(position));
        }
    });
    mHolder.mImageHolder.setAnimation(mFadeOut);

    return mView;
}

/*
 * This class is used to hold position of each component so it shouln't be
 * repeat again and again
 */

class ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImageHolder;
    TextView mTitleHolder, mOwnerHolder, mDateHolder;

}

private Bitmap getImagefromHashmap(int position) {

    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    ArrayList<String> mImagesList = mImages.get(mTitle.get(position));
    int mLastImagePostion = mLastImagePosition.get(position);

    if (mImagesList.size() - 1 > mLastImagePostion) {

        mLastImagePostion++;
        mLastImagePosition.put(position, mLastImagePostion);

    } else {

        mLastImagePostion = 0;
        mLastImagePosition.put(position, mLastImagePostion);

    }

    String mImageName = mImagesList.get(mLastImagePostion);
    // Get the AssetManager
    AssetManager manager = mContext.getAssets();

    // Read a Bitmap from Assets
    try {
        InputStream mOpen = manager.open(mImageName);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mOpen);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return Utils.resize(mBitmap,
            (int) (Utils.getDeviceWidth(mContext) / 2.5),
            Utils.getDeviceHeight(mContext) / 5);

}
}
```

So how to handle this situation or how to force getView() to be called after completion of animation for each row?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

- Create a Handler in your Adapter whose job will be to run Runnables.
- Each Runnable instance will be responsible for one currently-visible row in your list, fading images in and out every 3 seconds.
- On each call to getView, construct a new Runnable for that row, and call myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000) to start the fade timer.
- Keep the Runnable in ViewHolder, and when getView is called to recycle a row, call myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable) to stop the 3-second timer on the view that is being recycled.
- In the Runnable's code, run the animations to fade the old image out and the new image in. After the animation is started, have the Runnable post itself to the handler with the same 3-second delay. You'll probably want a Runnable sub-class so it can keep track of what the next image to show is.

Does that make sense? Do you need me to explain any part of it more? Do you need to see code?

EDIT:

Here is some code that I had in mind. No doubt I'm missing some pieces, but I hope you get the idea. Mainly the point is to have separate timers for each row, animating your images in and out. I agree with dor506 that you need more than one of each animation. In this solution you load new instances of the animations each time, so you can listen for their completion.

```
    // construct the handler inside your adapter's constructor so you know it is on the UI thread
    Handler myHandler = new Handler(); 

class FadeRunnable implements Runnable {
    ImageView iv;
    int position;

    public FadeRunnable(ImageView iv, int position) {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadeout);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(getImagefromHashmap(position));
                Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anim_fadein);
                iv.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        iv.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    }
}

/*
 * This class is used to hold position of each component so it shouln't be
 * repeat again and again
 */
class ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImageHolder;
    TextView mTitleHolder, mOwnerHolder, mDateHolder;
    FadeRunnable mRunnable;

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = convertView;
    if (mView == null) {
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.car_tile,
                null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.mTitleHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.titleHolder);
        mHolder.mOwnerHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.OwnerHolder);
        mHolder.mDateHolder = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateHolder);
        mHolder.mImageHolder = (ImageView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);

        mHolder.mRunnable = new FadeRunnable(mHolder.mImageHolder, position);

        mView.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(mHolder.mRunnable);
    }

/* Set Value to each row */
    mHolder.mTitleHolder.setText(mTitle.get(position));
    mHolder.mOwnerHolder.setText(mOwner.get(position));
    mHolder.mDateHolder.setText(Utils.millisToDate(
            Long.parseLong(mDate.get(position)), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"));
    mHolder.mImageHolder.setImageBitmap(getImagefromHashmap(position));

    myHandler.postDelayed(mHolder.mRunnable, 3000);

    return mView;
}
```

Two things I didn't do:

1) I didn't write the part inside the Runnable that puts itself back on the Handler for the next image. You could write yet another listener inside the first one that does that, or you could make FadeRunnable implement AnimationListener itself, and keep track of whether it is fading in our out, and do the right thing.

2) One thing this solution might need, but I don't want to try to code it now, is that you might need to cancel one runnable operating on a row, if that row gets recycled and another runnable wants to start fading a different animation in. It would work fine if the 3-second timer hasn't gone off yet, but if it has, and now the old runnable is doing the animations, then it might be a problem.

Comment: yes, It may help. But still If you can write code for your step that would be helpful to me because after doing too much stuff, i'm stuck :). thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with only one animation object (mFadeOut).
Calling to mFadeOut.setAnimationListener(...), will cause the last view (which returning from getView) to receive the callbacks (onAnimationEnd).
You should start by turning mFadeOut object into ArrayList or something like that, so you can support multiple animation (callbacks), or make mFadeOut object to be local for the getView method.

Comment: Good idea. But are you sure that would work properly? because wtihin 3 seconds getview is calling very quickly

Answer (score 0):

I think he main problem is that mFadeOut is acting always on the same reference of the view, so basically you are restarting the animation every time and of course it will be visible only in the last item.